# Using Html Agility Pack to capture inner text from a specific node

Tags: xpath, html-agility-pack

I am trying to grab the text "Record No: 1" and the two dates from the following html snippet:

```
<table class="Report">
<tbody>
<tr>
<td>
<font><b>Record No: 1</b><br>
<i>Original Date</i>: 12/16/2011<br>
<i>Original Entered Date</i>: 12/16/2011
<br>
<br>
</font>
</td>
</tr>
</tbody>
<table>
```

Using HTMLAgilityPack and the following code I've been able to get the record number but am not sure how to grab the dates.

```
var recordNum =report.Descendants()
.Where(a=>a.InnerText.Contains("Record No:"))
.Where(a => a.Name == "#text")
.First().InnerText;
```

Somehow I need to be able to grab the text following the "Original Date" node.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> *Somehow I need to be able to grab the text following the "Original Date" node.*

You can use the following XPath to select text nodes located after `i` element where inner text equals 'Original Date' :

```
//i[.='Original Date']/following-sibling::text()
```

Use the XPath as follow, for example :

```cs
var doc = new HtmlDocument();
....
var xpath = "//i[.='Original Date']/following-sibling::text()";
var result = doc.DocumentNode.SelectSingleNode(xpath);
Console.WriteLine(result.InnerText);
```

**<kbd>[`Demo`](https://dotnetfiddle.net/pBJ1Jr)</kbd>**

**output :**

```
: 12/16/2011
```

Comment: Always seems to come back with null.